MediaWiki - turn off automatic image inclusion?
Usually when a page is missing an image, the image is red-linked, allowing a user to click the link and upload the missing image.  However, while updating a page, mediawiki somehow automatically fulfilled a reference to an image by retrieving the image from what appears to be the central wikipedia repository. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be any way to replace this gratuitous image with the image we want to upload, and the one the software somehow found looks absolutely ridiculous. How can I turn off this 'feature' -- permanently?
Additional info:

MediaWiki 1.28
$wgForeignFileRepos is empty
$wgUseInstantCommons is false


What you describe should not happen; Do you have a screenshot?
